# Oracle apex grid calculations to_number hampering DA

Tags: oracle-apex

I have another requirement where the grid query is:

select to_char(kpi_1,'999,999,999,999.99'), to_char(kpi_2,'999,999,999,999.99'), to_char(kpi_3,'999,999,999,999.99') from kpi;

The KPI_1,KPI_2,KPI_3 columns are float in database but on grid they need to be represented in comma separated format. Therefor to_char is used.
And in processing they are changed back to to_number format to store in database.

Now i need to add dynamic action that would be kpi_2-kpi_1 = kpi_3.

So when i use dynamic action, set value: KPI_2-KPI_1, nothing happens.

Also when i use:  to_number(kpi_2,'999,999,999,999.99') - to_number(kpi_1,'999,999,999,999.99')

For values input there/existing data, there is no change in kpi_3 column which should have been calculated.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to return  to_number(kpi_2,'999,999,999,999.99') -to_number(kpi_1,'999,999,999,999.99') value using debug or in plsql raise_applicaiton_error.
if value return then try to set value using set value dynamic action.